# Dynamic method creation - define_singleton_method not using expected variables

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a class that can dynamically create methods. However, when I nest this code (the `add_method` method) in a recursive function, my newly created method takes the values passed in on the second recursion pass, rather than keeping the values on the first.

Running the sample code below might better explain my problem:

```
class Klass
  def initialize

    in_frame(:id => 'first_frame') do |frame|
      add_method "bar", {:frames => frame}

      in_frame({:id => 'second_frame'}, frame) do |frame|
        #do absolutely nothing
      end

    end
  end

  def add_method(name, identifiers)
    puts "adding the #{name} method with these frames #{identifiers}"

    define_singleton_method(name){
      puts "I shouldn't see a second_frame here:  #{identifiers}"
    }
  end

  def in_frame(identifier, frame=[], &block)
    frame << identifier
    block.call(frame)
  end
end

Foo = Klass.new
Foo.bar
```

the second frame is identified by "second_frame", but the method is created in the first_frame block, and the method is completely created and finished before the second, recursive code block begins.

So if that's the case, why does Foo.bar return second_frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

You need to create a copy of the `frame` object before manipulating it in `in_frame`.

```
def in_frame(identifier, frame=[], &block)
  frame = frame.dup << identifier
  block.call(frame)
end
```

#### Explanation

The behaviour you observe is perfectly valid, when you follow object identities. So let's follow the `frame` object on it's journey :)

```
1 def initialize
2   in_frame(:id => 'first_frame') do |frame|
3     add_method "bar", {:frames => frame}
4     in_frame({:id => 'second_frame'}, frame) do |frame|
5       #do absolutely nothing
6     end
7   end
8 end
```

In line 1 we call `in_frame` with the arguments `:id => 'first_frame'`, and implicitly `frame=[]`. Here `frame` is given birth as a new array to which `:id => 'first_frame'` is appended.

At the beginning of line 3 our `frame` looks like `[:id => 'first_frame']` - it is still the same object we created in line 1. We execute `add_method`, passing our precious `frame` as an argument. Within `add_method` we do a `puts` which prints the `frame` in its current state.

> adding the bar method with these frames
>   {:frames=>[{:id=>"first_frame"}]}

Furthermore, we define a method `bar`, which holds *a reference* to `frame`, but does not yet do anything with it.

In line 4 we call `in_frame` with an empty block. `in_frame` takes our `frame` (still the same object) as an argument and appends `:id => 'second_frame'` to it. Now our frame looks like `[{:id=>"first_frame"}, {:id=>"second_frame"}]`.

When we call `Foo.bar` later, we print our `frame` again (which is still the very same object as in line 1), because it is saved as a reference in the binding of method `bar`.

> I shouldn't see a second_frame here:  {:frames=>[{:id=>"first_frame"},
>   {:id=>"second_frame"}]}

During the whole journey, we manipulate the same `frame` object: printing it, appending things to it, and printing it again.

Comment: Perfect answer! It solves my problem, and has walked me through the problem so that I now have greater understanding. I can't thank you enough.